# copy files using FileOutputStream, Cannot find symbol when complie

Tags: java, input, output

I tried to copy the contents of a file using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream, with the following code:

```
public class Example1App {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example1 program= new Example1();
    program.start();
   }
}
```

and

```
import java.io.*;
public class Example1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
       FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
       int c;
       while ((c = fin.read()) != -1)
       fout.write(c);
       fin.close();
       fout.close();
     }
   }
```

When compile, the error message is :
cannot find symbol
    program.start();
           ^
  symbol:   method start()
  location: variable program of type Example1
Can anyone help me to explain why this happened?
Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there is no method in your `Example1` class named `start`.

What you probably want to do is:

1. Create a `start()` method in your `Example1` class
2. Better yet, instead of `start()`, name the method `copy` and give it parameters: `copy(String arg0, String arg1)`

So, you'll get:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Example1 {
    public void copy(String inName, String outName) throws Exception {
       FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(inName);
       FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outName);
       int c;
       while ((c = fin.read()) != -1)
       fout.write(c);
       fin.close();
       fout.close();
     }
}
```

And:

```
public class Example1App {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Example1 program = new Example1();
       try {
         program.copy(args[0], args[1]);
       } catch (Exception e) {
         // Generally, you want to handle exceptions rather 
         // than print them, and you should handle some 
         // exceptions in copy() so you can close any open files.
         e.printStackTrace(); 
       }
   }
}
```

(and really, you can just combine these into one program - just move the `main` method from Example1App to Example1, and delete Example1App)

Comment: Thank you David! Could you explain a bit more about how to create a start method in Example1 class? I am a real beginner here..

Comment: About the 2nd option, I wrote public class Example1 (String arg[0], args[1]) {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {... But the when compile, the error says: error: '{' expected
public class Example1 (String arg[0], args[1])

Comment: See edited answer. Bottom line is, you've already got it, mostly.

Comment: Thanks a lot David! That makes much more sense now. I will try the new code.

Comment: Now it says: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
       program.copy(args[0], args[1]); I tried to put them it try and catch (Exception e) blocks and it didn't work either..

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a non-existent method, like the message says. Just get rid of the first class altogether and execute the second class directly, with 'java Example1'.